# Open View everytime my app is opened, only if use chooses to

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm writing a game for iOS and I was wondering how to make the instructions View Controller open every time the app is opened. I want to have a switch that says "Show me this every time." and if they switch it to no the instructions will no longer show up when the app is opened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store the switch value, then check for it every time app launches in Your app delegate, applicationDidBecomeActive method.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
   BOOL switchState = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"switchKey"];
   if(switchState) {
       //If switch is on create the instance of InstructionViewController
       //you can call any of InstructionViewController methods on it.
       InstructionViewController* intructionsViewController = [[InstructionViewController alloc] init];
       //Present the instance of instruction view on top of your current view
       [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a function that runs everytime the app opens? Viewdidload only runs when you open it if you take it out of the multitasking bar.

Comment: You can use your Application delegate applicationDidBecomeActive method, I edited the answer :)

Comment: Ok, so in my instructions view controller I have two functions, one to set the value of the switch and one to retrieve it. Can I call those functions from the applicationDidBecomActive function?

Comment: Also, is it possible to performSegueWithIdentifier from the app delegate?

Comment: Updated my answer to be more accurate. Hope it helps :)
I am not sure about performSequeWithIdentifier, but if you can retrieve the view controller on which you want to perform segue you should have no problems.

Comment: I just get a black screen, the InstructionsViewController's viewDidLoad runs though